# Make model, migration and controller with one command and right plural ending

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to figure out the one command-line command to make Model, migration and controller with the right plural ending and case like the following example:

*Model:* **Post**.php

*Migration:* ###_ create_ **posts** _table.php

*Controller:* **Posts**Controller.php

I have tried

```
php artisan make:model Posts -m -c
```

and

```
php artisan make:model Post -m -c
```

and

a few other commands but I can't seem to get the magical one that solves them all.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for you

```
php artisan make:model Post -mcr
```

This will create a model `Post`, controller `PostController` and migration `xxxx_create_posts_table`

Comment: Thank you, this is almost right! BUT according to convention it should be PostsController (plural on Posts - in the controller but model shall be Post)...

Comment: @Olof I don't think so. Controller created during `php artisan make:auth` have same name as in my answer. Controllers are like `RegisterController ` etc

Comment: Guatam hmm.. I am basing my naming on Jeffery Ways tutorials on laracast.. Maybe there are two different schools?

Comment: Interesting. Looking through my projects I see the singular camel case. This is an extremely relevant question.

Comment: I'm talking about basic naming way and most of the developer follows above way. That is table name plural verb all in small letter, model name singular verb with first letter capital and then all small letter, controller are as described above. There might be other convension though. Main aim is to make code simple and easy to understand :)

Comment: Completely agree with you on the "Main aim is to make code simple and easy to understand :)"  -  In a way I kind a like the way you are describing better then Jeffs... but on the other hand I am not Jeff.... :)