# Is there a way of set the name of the controller differently when using the -c option for making a model?

Tags: laravel

When doing `php artisan make:model Post -mc` the resulted naming convention will be:

- model: Post
- migration file: ...create_posts_table
- controller: PostController

Is there a way of setting the name of the controller to **Posts**Controller (plural) when doing the artisan command?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not. Look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730191/make-model-migration-and-controller-with-one-command-and-right-plural-ending

Comment: @VaheShak Thank you. I will check it out!